# Ansible playbook replace module doesn't behave as expected

Tags: ansible

Using Ansible 2.5.1 here

```
ansible-playbook 2.5.1
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14) [GCC 7.5.0]
```

I'm testing a simple `replace` for a grafana config file. In this file, I want to replace the default `domain = localhost` with the actual hostname `domain = {{ ansible_host }}`

I've created a simple test playbook for that:

```
---
- name: Test replace
  hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Update Grafana configuration - General
    replace:
      path: '/path/to/grafana_config_template.ini'
      regexp: "{{ item.From }}"
      replace: "{{ item.To }}"
      before: "{{ item.Before }}"
      after: "{{ item.After }}"
    with_items:
      - { From: "^(domain = localhost)$", To: "domain = foo", After: "[server]", Before: "[database]" } #doesn't work
      - { From: "^(domain = localhost)$", To: "domain = foo", After: "", Before: "[database]" } #works
      - { From: "^(domain = localhost)$", To: "domain = foo", After: "[server]", Before: "" } #works
```

An extract file for grafana config looks like this:

```
...
#################################### Server ##############################
[server]
# Protocol (http, https, socket)
...

# The public facing domain name used to access grafana from a browser
domain = localhost

# Redirect to correct domain if host header does not match domain
# Prevents DNS rebinding attacks
enforce_domain = false

...
#################################### Database ############################
[database]
...
```

When I run the playbook with `$ ansible-playbook test.yml -v`, I get:

```
PLAY [Test config] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Update Grafana configuration - General] ******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'To': u'domain = foo', u'After': u'[server]', u'From': u'^(domain = localhost)$', u'Before': u'.*[database]'}) => {"changed": false, "item": {"After": "[server]", "Before": ".*[database]", "From": "^(domain = localhost)$", "To": "domain = foo"}, "msg": ""}
changed: [localhost] => (item={u'To': u'domain = foo', u'After': u'', u'From': u'^(domain = localhost)$', u'Before': u'[database]'}) => {"changed": true, "item": {"After": "", "Before": "[database]", "From": "^(domain = localhost)$", "To": "domain = foo"}, "msg": "1 replacements made"}
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'To': u'domain = foo', u'After': u'[server]', u'From': u'^(domain = localhost)$', u'Before': u''}) => {"changed": false, "item": {"After": "[server]", "Before": "", "From": "^(domain = localhost)$", "To": "domain = foo"}, "msg": ""}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

As you can see, the "After" OR "Before" works, but not both together. And yes, I do know that those 3 replacements are mutually exclusive. i.e. if #2 runs, #3 won't do anything. Also, for my test, I'm replacing with `foo` instead of `{{ansible_host}}`.

Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT 1: Based on the comment, I tried the following:

```
- { From: "^(domain = localhost)$", To: "domain = foo", After: "", Before: "[server]" }
- { From: "^(domain = localhost)$", To: "domain = foo", After: "[database]", Before: "" }
```

I was expecting both replace to fail/do nothing since the `domain = localhost` is **AFTER** `[server]` and **BEFORE** `[database]`, but both got replaced... There's no indication why the after/before got ignored.

Comment: Have you considered using Ansible [lineinfile module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/lineinfile_module.html)? From what I understand, it might serve your purpose better.

Comment: As it does not look like you need `before` and `after`, I would not bother with them or use the lineinfile module as suggested above. The problem here is probably, that `before` and `after` take regexes and `[]` are character groups, so your `before` and `after` match one character of the list you provide. You need to escape `[` and `]`.

Comment: @toydarian, I would agree with your comment, but `before:"[tag]"` or `after:"[tag]"` individually works... So it seems it's not about the regex not matching. I will try however to set a `before` or `after` with tag that would match the text I'm trying to replace, just to make sure the issue is not with the actual regex.

Comment: @seshadri_c, Thanks, I will try, but it still doesn't explain with `replace` doesn't behave as expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `replace` module by default replaces all occurances of the `regexp` found in `path`.  Quoting from official documentation:

> - This module will replace all instances of a pattern within a file.
> - It is up to the user to maintain idempotence by ensuring that the same pattern would never match any replacements made.

To limit this, we can use `before` and `after`.

**Now my interpretation of this:**

While the documentation doesn't say anything about whether `before` and `after` are references in the same line or *n lines* above and below. In my opinion, for `replace` to work reliably the `before` and `after` expressions should be on the same line.

We can demonstrate this with below example:

Let's consider a `sample.txt` with below contents:

```
ruby ansible chef
foo ansible baz
python ansible saltstack
```

Now let's say I wanted to change `ansible` to `bar` only on the line `foo ansible baz`, then I would have a task like:

```yaml
  - replace:
      path: "sample.txt"
      regexp: "ansible"
      replace: "bar"
      after: "foo"
      before: "baz"
```

Now when we run this task:

```
 ruby ansible chef
-foo ansible baz
+foo bar baz
 python ansible saltstack
```

*Also there is a bug in Ansible [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/replace_module.html) mentioned in the Notes And this affects versions lower than 2.7.10.*

> - As of Ansible 2.7.10, the combined use of before and after works properly. If you were relying on the previous incorrect behavior, you may be need to adjust your tasks. See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31354 for details.

**Now the solution**

As I commented on the question, there are better options to achieve your objective. Apart from the lineinfile module, you can use the [ini_file module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/ini_file_module.html):

```yaml
  - ini_file:
      path: '/path/to/grafana_config_template.ini'
      section: "server"
      option: "{{ item.opt }}"
      value: "{{ item.val }}"
    with_items:
    - { opt: "domain", val: "foo" }
    - { opt: "enforced_domain", val: "true" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives. I will investigate those and I believe you are right about before/after being on the same line...

Comment: The `ini_file` module does work, but it changes the order of the fields, which makes the comments out of place and hard to understand.

I tried both `replace` (considering DOTALL as explained in the doc: this regex pattern is working: [link]regexr.com/5fbt4) and `lineinfile` modules and both fail with finding the right regex.

While the example I gave above does have only 1 occurrence in the file, that's not the case for "host" which I need to replace in different sections.

Comment: With so many options in Ansible to manipulate files, `template` is almost forgotten. :) But if you care about the contents of file to be exactly how you want. The [template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/template_module.html) would be a good choice.